# Command line output to split files

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008

I want to be able to split an output from a command line that goes into a file.
I want either or both of the following ways to split:

- Split based on file size. If it gets to say 500kb, then create a new file
- Split based on lines in file. If it gets to 1000 lines, then create a new file

Of course, this also means I need a variable name for the output

This is the command I'm running now:

```
java -jar "C:\Processors\myProcessor.jar" >> "C:\Processors\myprocessor.log"
```

Would like 'myprocessor.log' to be split in files accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The split command does exactly what you're after, with options to split on file size or on line count. From [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split):

> split - split a file into pieces
>
> Output  fixed-size  pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is `x'.  With no INPUT, or  when INPUT is -, read standard input.
>
> ...snip...
>
> -b, --bytes=SIZE
>   put SIZE bytes per output file
>
> -l, --lines=NUMBER
>   put NUMBER lines per output file

You can get the split command in the [GnuWin32 CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) for use on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without modifying myProcessor.jar, then you'll need to post-process the log file.  I suspect you could do this within Powershell but it is not immediately apparent to me how.  There is nothing in Windows to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you're trying to do requires writing a script at least (command line only won't help)

for scripting purposes of such i would recommend writing a Ruby script (Ruby is a very powerful and extremely easy to learn language - very friendly). writing a batch file to do it will eat your brains (at least it would mine)

Comment: yeah... but I see no other way. I would have to rewrite all the code.